# Unable to access string in another method

Tags: c#, methods

I have spent the last few days trying to figure this out with no luck, I hope you can help out, i am very new to c#.

Below is part of my console application, The two different methods are in their own separate timers that run at different speeds, so they cannot be in the same method.  I am using JSON.net / JObject that is being sent json via httpclient.

I am trying to access the results of

```
JObject Grab = JObject.Parse(httpResponse(@"https://api.example.jp/json.json").Result);

string itemTitle = (string)Grab["channel"]["item"][0]["title"];
```

from a different method, using this code

```
Console.WriteLine(itemTitle);
```

I have tried so many different ways, but all have been unsuccessful. 
Below is the full section of code regarding Json.net.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
internal class Program
{
        ...other code

    public static async Task<string> httpResponse(string url)
    {
        HttpClientHandler httpHandler = new HttpClientHandler()
        {
            AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate
        };
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(httpHandler))
            return await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);
    }

    public static void JSONUpdateTimer(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        JObject Grab = JObject.Parse(httpResponse(@"https://api.example.jp/json.json").Result);

        string itemTitle = (string)Grab["channel"]["item"][0]["title"];
        Console.WriteLine(itemTitle);

        JSONUpdate.Interval = JSONUpdateInterval();
        JSONUpdate.Start();
    }

    public static void SecondTimer(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(itemTitle);
        ...other Commands using "itemTitle"
    }
}
}
```

I have a bad feeling i am missing something so obvious that i will face palm if its pointed out. But i will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare a string field named itemTitle as a member of the class, outside any methods.

```
internal class Program
{
    static string itemTitle; 
    //other code...
}
```

In your methods, don't declare a new variable, just reference the field.

```
public static void JSONUpdateTimer(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    //...
    itemTitle = (string)Grab["channel"]["item"][0]["title"];
    //...
}
```

Variables declared inside a method are locally scoped to that method and do not exist outside of it.

Comment: Thank you so much, i have spent so much time on this, i cant believe how simple it is.